# How to find which word contained within sentence

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a list of suppliers in a column (column A) in Google Sheets, and I have transactions list from my bank. Each item description (column B) in bank transactions list is a mess of the supplier name and numbers. For each item description I want to find a matching supplier name from the suppliers list. How can I do this?

Comment: hey Tim, you can use a little bit of regex to do this, having trouble conceptualising your issue tho, can you create an example of your sheet and share it here?

Comment: If they match what Will you do, Mark it? Or you Will give the supplier name on other column ini your bank trans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B), 
 LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(A2:A, 1, 1))))))
```

[image: y]

Comment: Just a follow up question... The supplier list contains just the keyword of the supplier's business name (e.g. "Abc" in your example above) but I'd like to have a separate column (lets say column D here) where I can optionally have the full business name (e.g. "Abc Consulting Ltd". Is there a way to amend the formula so that it checks if there's a full business name in column D and returns this if there is a value, otherwise returns the supplier abbreviation in column A?